# Getting members from a list in PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

I have to make a rule to return the line's for the station entered

But in order to get all of the line's, I'd have to make a rule like:

```
line(Line,ListofStations) :-  
    station(ListofStations,[Line]);
    station(ListofStations,[_,Line]);
    station(ListofStations,[Line,_]);
    station(ListofStations,[Line,_,_]);
    station(ListofStations,[_,Line,_]);
    station(ListofStations,[Line,_,_]).
```

I'd need to use a predicate to make the rule smaller, 
but the member function just returns true and the rule below works for all cases except ones which have more than one element in a list.

```
line(Line,ListofStations):- station(ListofStations,[Line]).
```

Facts:

```
station(oxford_circus,[bakerloo,central,victoria]). 
station(embankment,[bakerloo,northern]). 
station(elephantandcastle,[bakerloo]).
station(nottingHill_gate,[central]). 
station(lancaster_gate,[central]).
station(tottenham_court_road,[central]). 
station(chancery_lane,[central]). 
station(liverpool_street,[central,metropolitan]). 
station(bethnal_green,[central]).
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a correct answer for a station. I know the answers seems obvious, but it would make the question better to have a correct solution as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want lines from station or stations from line but... in both cases, I think you need the `member/2` predicate (that is ISO, as far I know, and supported by SWI-Prolog).

I suggest something like

```
line(Line, ListofStations) :-
  station(ListofStations, LineList),
  member(Line, LineList).
```

that works in both directions.

By example, when I call

```
 line(central, L)
```

I get (`L` is unified with) `oxford_circus`, `nottingHill_gate`, `lancaster_gate`, `tottenham_court_road`, `chancery_lane`, `liverpool_street` and `bethnal_green`

and when I call

```
line(L, oxford_circus)
```

I get `bakerloo`, `central` and `victoria`.